# Design for REST API client

Tags: java, rest, design-patterns

I want to create a REST API client, which for the same REST API server will call different URLs. This different calls will return JSON and XML to the client. 
**What would be a good design pattern for this situation ?**

So far I've come up with a combination of Strategy and Command:

```
public interface IRestCall {
    /** Setup the URL for the call. */
    void setup(IRestSetup setup) throws Exception;
    /** Execute the call, using the URL set up in the first step. 
     * @throws Exception */
    void call() throws Exception;
    /** Process the result and return to the user. */
    <T> T getResult(IRestResultProcessor<T> result) throws Exception;
}
```

This is the Strategy interface. The context for the Strategy will 
be in some Get/Post/Put methods in a Facade class.

IRestSetup and IRestResultProcessor are interfaces for Command objects 
which will setup the URL for the REST API and will process the result.

Comment: The good design to parse the JSON at server side is to use GSON. http://www.journaldev.com/2321/gson-example-tutorial-parse-json
You have to design proper JavaBeans to parse and validate the JSON response.
For XML, You can use JAXB Binding.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this is just a small part of my question. Plus I am interested in design and not a specific framework.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need some special design pattern to handle that situation. I personally would just add some generic methods for  GET and POST requests. The code below handles only GET requests but it should be enough to get an idea what I mean.

Your client method processing GET requests might look something like

```
/**
restUrl - url to the service 
resClz - the actual POJO object that the JSON or XML response will be mapped to
resType - type of MIME object returned by the server (typically MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON or MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
*/  
  <T> T doRestGet(String restUrl, Class<T> resClz, String resType){

        T obj;
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();            

        WebTarget target = client.target(UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost:8088/Your_WS_root").build()); 

        try{

         obj =(T) target.path(restUrl).request()
              .accept(resType).get().readEntity(resClz);


        }catch(Exception e){
         System.out.println(e);//log or propagate the exception

        return null;
        }
        return obj;
}
```

Your server method might look something like

```
@GET
  @Path("/userMsg")
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public UserMessage getUsersOne() {

   UserMessage uMsg = new UserMessage();
   uMsg.setUserMsg("successful call");
   return uMsg;
  }
```

Now you'd call your service

```
UserMessage uMsg = (UserMessage)doRestGet("userMsg", UserMessage.class, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON );
```

Comment: Which framework is best suitable to implement this ?

Comment: Well, Jersey is the reference implementation of the JAX-RS specification and it's probably the easiest REST framework to use (at least for  me)